# Jackcess equivalents for simple SQL SELECT statements

Tags: java, ms-access, select, join, jackcess

Can someone please explain how I might use Jackcess to implement the equivalent of the following SQL queries?

```sql
SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = '1'

SELECT name FROM table INNER JOIN table ON table.id = table2.id
```

Comment: Have you considered using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html)? For more information, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Comment: unfortunately i'm developing just a part of the project, i have to use jackcess, the choice it isn't mine

Answer (score 3):

**Re: your first query (SELECT ... FROM tableName WHERE ...)**

In its simplest form you could use the "Searching for a row with a specific column value" example under "Sample code" on the main Jackcess page [here](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/), i.e.,

```java
Table table = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("my.mdb")).getTable("MyTable");
Row row = CursorBuilder.findRow(table, Collections.singletonMap("a", "foo"));
if(row != null) {
    System.out.println("Found row where 'a' == 'foo': " + row);
} else {
    System.out.println("Could not find row where 'a' == 'foo'");
}
```

To loop through multiple matching rows you could do something like this

```java
Table table = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("my.mdb")).getTable("MyTable");
Cursor cursor = CursorBuilder.createCursor(table);
while (cursor.findNextRow(Collections.singletonMap("a", "foo"))) {
    Row row = cursor.getCurrentRow();
    System.out.println(String.format(
            "a='%s', SomeFieldName='%s'.", 
            row.get("a"), 
            row.get("SomeFieldName")));
}
```

or, as @jtahlborn suggests in a comment below,

```java
Table table = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("my.mdb")).getTable("MyTable");
Cursor cursor = CursorBuilder.createCursor(table);
for (Row row : cursor.newIterable().addMatchPattern("a", "foo")) {
    System.out.println(String.format(
            "a='%s', SomeFieldName='%s'.", 
            row.get("a"), 
            row.get("SomeFieldName")));
}
```

**Re: your second query (SELECT ... FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON ...)**

You could use one `for` or `while` loop (similar to above) to iterate through the relevant rows in one table, and use an inner `for` or `while` loop to iterate through the related rows in the other (related) table. If the two tables have an existing "Relationship" in Access (a.k.a. "foreign key constraint") Jackcess has a [Joiner](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/healthmarketscience/jackcess/util/Joiner.html) class that may be of assistance, discussed [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/discussion/456474/thread/dfd5e080/).

---

If you require further assistance you will need to *try writing some code for yourself* and then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) showing the code you are attempting to use and the *specific issue* you have with it.

Comment: i'm sorry but when the code arrive at the "while" condition that you wrote doesn't enter,  jump over the "while" block

Comment: @Shiroga I have updated my answer. (It was missing the `Table table = ...` in the second example.)

Comment: @Shiroga re: Comments to your answer (which has been deleted) - Stack Overflow is a "Question and Answer" site; it does not encourage long discussions. The idea is that someone asks *one specific question*, people offer direct answers to that question, the answers attract up/down votes based on their quality, and ideally one of those answers is [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238021). Follow-up questions are discouraged because they detract from the focus of the original question+answer exchange. *Try writing some code* and then create a new question if you still need help.

Comment: Note, you can simplify the loop a lot using the IterableBuilder: `for(Row row : cursor.newIterable().addMatchPattern("a", "foo")) {`.